# Calculating the volume of a cylinder.

Tags: functions, volume

Let $V = \{(x, y, z): x^2 + y^2 ≤ 4$ and $0 \le z \le 4\}$ be a cylinder and let $P$ be
the plane through $(4, 0, 2)$, $(0, 4, 2)$ and $(−4, −4, 4)$. Compute the volume
of $C$ below the plane $P$.

I have absolutely no idea how to start this question. I was thinking using Cavalieri’s Principle but I'm not quite sure how to or if there's another way of working it out. Please help.

Comment: The standard way would be to find the equation of the plane, and use it to find the region bounded by below by the plane and by above by the cylinder. Are you familiar with double and triple integrals? Cylindrical coordinates are probably best here.

Comment: Cylindical coordinates and triple integrals both sound familiar. So would you recommend Cylindical coordinates and how should I start? Thanks

Comment: There is no need of any integral. Imagine you have two identical copies of a cylinder with the top cut at some angle. The top face of them are ellipses instead of circles. Now flip one of the cylinder upside down and align/match the two elliptical faces, you get back an ordinary cylinder....

Answer (score 0):

the normal of the plane is given by taking the cross product of the first point minus the second times the first point times the third. It is i+j+6k. Then the equation of the plane is given by equating the dot product of the normal times the diference between (x,y,z) and the first point with 0. Is is z=(16-x-y)/6=(i6-rcosa-rcosa)/16. Now the volume is given by taking the double integral in polar coordinates over the region 0<=r<=1 and 0<=a<=2.pi of (i6-rcosa-rcosa)/16.